# Flutter TextFormField wrap text and automatically adapt height

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, how to utilize `TextFormField` widget which wrap it's text and auto-size height based on current text as user type?

Answer (score 3):

Simply set the `maxLines` property of your TextFormField widget to null it will automatically resize.

Tested on DartPad using this example:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      child: TextFormField(maxLines: null),
    );
  }
}
```